# Maximize windows without maximize button

Tags: gnome

I am using IntelliJ IDEA on Ubuntu 20.04. Some of its dialogs pop up and do not have a button to maximize it, even though it has the handles to manually change its size. This particular dialog has a lot of information to convey, I like it to be maximized, but after some whatever, the dialog sometimes loses my carefully manually-resized “maximized-like” positioning. I wish there was an easy way to maximize this dialog.

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> does not work for this window.

Drag and snap does not work for this window.

This used to be possible with the extension [Window Buttons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/426/window-buttons/), but that no longer works.

I understand this may be an IntelliJ IDEA problem, but I have little confidence in that getting any traction, so I'm looking for an Ubuntu/Gnome solution or workaround.

I am wondering if there are any other ways. (I'd be fine with a command-line solution that I can hook up to a shortcut of sorts.) There's just not much I can find (googling for “gnome” and “maximize” mostly just brings me to the Ubuntu 12 era when Gnome reportedly removed the maximize buttons for everyone). Thank you.

[image: IntelliJ IDEA commit dialog on Ubuntu 20.04]

Comment: This looks like a modal dialog, I don't think it's *supposed* to be maximizable.

Comment: That's fair, but since it's resizable... and since I can resize to look as much as maximizable... it feels like it could be maximized -- or at least that such could be mimicked.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely annoying. We have large monitors and we cannot maximize the 'modal' window. And Jetbrains by the way does encourage to make usage of the keyboard and shortcuts. I have something for you. On Ubuntu you can increase the size of a Window using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>. Then use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> and the arrow keys. The window is maximized into the direction of the key.
<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>LEFT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>RIGHT</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>DOWN</kbd> and finally <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>UP</kbd>.
Seems Intellij records the size of the modal.
Example. You commit your changes, (<kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>), resize the modal window as explained above,  you do <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then try to commit a second time (<kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and the size of the window is restored.